# Loading WMS in OpenLayers

Tags: javascript, openlayers, wms

I am trying to load this https://mrdata.usgs.gov/services/ardf?request=GetCapabilities&service=WMS&version=1.3.0&  WMS in OpenLayers3. However, it has two layers (layer within layer e.g. layers 1 and 2  on the picture).
[image: Here is how it looks]

How do I get the layer to be displayed in my Browser? What do I write under "LAYERS" so that I can display both of the layers 1 and 2 on picture.

```
var GEBCO_NORTH_POLAR_VIEW = new ol.layer.Tile({
                            source: new ol.source.TileWMS(({
                              url: "https://mrdata.usgs.gov/services/ardf?",
                              attributions: '<a href="http://USGS</a>',
                              params: {
                                "LAYERS": "ardf-high",
                                "TILED": "true",
                                "VERSION": "1.1.0"},
                            })),
                            //crossOrigin: 'anonymous',
                            title: "GEBCO Grid North Polar View",
                            opacity: 1.000000,
                           });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can name as many layers as you want in the `LAYERS` parameter so you should write:

```
"LAYERS": "ardf,ardf-high"
```

**UPDATE**

Looking at the [capabilities](https://mrdata.usgs.gov/services/ardf?request=getcapabilities&service=WMS&version=1.3.0&) more closely, there is in fact just **one** layer `ardf` that you should add to your map. It consists of **twio** sub layers one of which is displayed at scales before 1:5M and one to display at scales below 1:5M.

The two sub layers can not be seen at the same time, so you can either add the grouped layer `ardf` or the 2 sub layers `ardf-high,ardf-low` but the output is the same.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Unfortunately, this still doesn't display any output.  Is there a special trick with layer wrapped in another level?

Comment: shouldn't be, does the 2nd one just display a blank image over the other?

Comment: So, when I access the service on QGIS, clicking on any level layer gives same (expected) display but I don't get any response in the browser.  @IanTurton

Comment: Thank you for the response. Do I add this as a parameter? @TomazicM .

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible to show both layers at the same time; that's not an issue of OpenLayers, it's just how it's configured in the service.  That is the service is configured to only show one layer at a time based on the map scale, as it tells us in the GetCapabilities response.

```
<Name>ardf-high</Name>    
...
<MaxScaleDenominator>5e+06</MaxScaleDenominator>

<Name>ardf-low</Name>
...
<MinScaleDenominator>5e+06</MinScaleDenominator>
```

You might as well just specify the root layer `ARDF` as there's no alternative styling on other options to choose between the layers `ardf-low` and `ardf-high`